# Keeping the user session in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying a phonegap app.What I want to know is the best method to keep the user logged in even after the app is closed and re opened without asking the user to re login ? Should I use local storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes - that is my approach. Do remember though that depending on the device OS, the data stored could be less secure.

I don't know if you can 100% eliminate risks, but you can reduce them.

I have two keys.

LOCALKEY which is a random hash, stored locally on the device.

SERVERKEY which is a hash of LOCALKEY and kept on my server.

When LOCALKEY reconnects to the server, the server will hash LOCALKEY and use it to find SERVERKEY.

If SERVERKEY is not found, then either someone has manually created a key, or its a first time connection.

And why do I make SERVERKEY? Why not store LOCALKEY on my server?

It is an added layer of security/privacy... I have worked for a client in Germany who explained some of the efforts Germany have to ensure a respect for privacy. By hashing a hash, you can 100% hand on heart say there is no direct copy of device data held on your server - and if you server is ever hacked, the ability to trace the source of the hash is at best, limited.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanx a lot :) I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely make use of your local storage..but, i will like to give some explanation on some other storage style you can use

**localStorage:** This can store your information, for as long as you do not delete them.
for instance, if you want to store a JSON in your localStorage, you have localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(message));

to get your data, you have var gm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));

Delete: localStorage.removeItem('data);
delete window.localStorage['data'];
or
window.localStorage.clear();

you can make use of the delete, after the user logs out of the application.

**sessionStorage:** This stores information as long as the session goes. Usually until the user closes the interface.

Comment: Thanx a lot :) I figured it out :)